# Intersecting multiple classified rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con, forest-ecology

I have 3 raster files:

1. A transform aspect (TRASP) layer (classified into 2 strata-(0-0.5, 0.5-1))
2. A canopy cover layer (classified into quantiles-5 breaks)
3. A canopy height layer(classified into quantiles-5 breaks)

The purpose is to take these three layers and do 2x5x5 to get 50 strata,

How can I do this in the raster calculator or any other tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

I tried using the simple `"TRASP"*"canopy_cover"*"canopy_height"` in the raster calculator but I got a big maximum value, so I don't know if it's correct or not. I also tried using `Con(((IsNull(TRASP))|(IsNull(canopy_cover))|(IsNull(canopy_height))),0,1)` suggested in another question, but that returned an error.

Comment: This is a good task for Combine tool, after reclass into integers.

Comment: Yep that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve this problem in ArcGIS:

1. Reclassify these three rasters using the 'Reclassify' tool. Specifically, reclassify `"Rec_TRASP"` into 100, 200; reclassify `"Rec_canopy_cover"` into 10, 20, 30, 40, 50; reclassify `"Rec_canopy_height"` into 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
2. Try `"Rec_TRASP"+"Rec_canopy_cover"+"Rec_canopy_height"` in the raster calculator.
3. Now, the output_raster values represent the corresponding strata you want. For example, the raster value '132' represent this grid cell belongs to first class in raster `"Rec_TRASP"`, third class in raster `"canopy_cover"`, second class in raster `"canopy_height"`.

Comment: Yep that worked